# Insert a csv file as embedded object in a word document using Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I generated Word document file using Apache POI but want to insert a CSV file as an embedded object that can be opened (double clicking on it).Is there any code snippet available using Apache POI Java program.

**Used below code to Generate Word Document:**

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;  
import java.io.OutputStream;  
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;  
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;  
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;  
public class ParagraphExample {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();  
        try(OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("TestResults.doc")) {  
            XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();  
            XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
            run.setText("Hello, This is Test Execution Results. This paragraph is written "+  
            "by using XWPFParagrah.");  
            doc.write(os);  
        }catch(Exception e) {  
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Word doesn't have attachments. I assume you mean an embedded object.